# Difference between 'type' => 'text' and WP_Customize_Control

Tags: php, theme-customizer, api

Heyo,

I was wondering if there is any difference between the `'type' => 'text'` option in the `$wp_customize->add_control` control

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'textfield_1_control', array(
    'label' => __('Textfield 1', 'cvh'),
    'section' => 'test_section',
    'settings' => 'textfield_setting_1',
    'type' => 'text',
    'description' => 'type => text',
));
```

and the `new WP_Customize_Control` control.

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'textfield_2_control', array(
    'label' => __('Textfield 2', 'cvh'),
    'section' => 'test_section',
    'settings' => 'textfield_setting_2',
    'description' => 'WP_Customize_Control',
)));
```

The output is the exact same (textfield).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really much of a difference for the default controls. Using the Class is needed for using custom built controls. So basically your first example is the short form of the second one only available for core controls.

For details have a look at [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/#controls).